# Issue Playing HTML5 Video in Firefox on Linux

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

When I enter a WebM video URL in a web browser on Windows 7, the video automatically starts playing. But in Firefox on a Linux system, when I enter a WebM video URL it asks me if I want to download that video file, rather than automatically playing it in the browser.

[image]

This may be a silly question with a super simple answer, but what do I need to do to make this video play within the browser, rather than asking me if I want to download it?

When I try the same thing in Chrome in my Linux environment, the video automatically plays within the web browser as I would hope, so it seems to be something specific to Firefox in Linux that I need to change.

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was irrelevant to this question specifically. Try downloading the file then from your file browser right click->open with->firefox and see if that does anything.

Comment: I tried that too, it does the same thing, where it offers to let me download the video.

Comment: Go to this link http://webm.html5.org/ and what version Firefox do you have.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I just figured it out as well when I went to your html5test.com website. Apparently this machine had Firefox 10.0.6 installed! So obviously I need to update it to a more current version. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. And is your problem resolved?

Comment: Yep, updating to Firefox 21.0 definitely fixed the issue. Sorry for such a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this link http://webm.html5.org to verify that you can play WebM videos and make sure you update to a newer version of Firefox.

Comment: But I'm trying this with a WebM video, not an MP4, so that shouldn't be the issue here. The simple test I'm trying works in Firefox in my Windows 7 environment, just not in Firefox in my Linux environment.

Comment: Silly question but what version of Firefox? and click here http://webm.html5.org/